# How to arrange HTML5 web page elements?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make a sample web page to get acquainted with HTML5, and I'd like to try replicating Facebook's page layout; that is, the header that spans the entire width of the screen, a small footer at the bottom, and a three-column main body, consisting of a list of links on the left, the main content in the middle, and an optional section on the right (for ads, frames, etc.). It's neat and displays well in multiple window sizes.

So far, I've tried to accomplish this with a `<header>`, `<footer>` and a `<nav>` and `<section>` block, respectively. There's a few anomalies with the page, however. The footer (which contains a simple text block with copyright info) appears at the top-right of the page below the header when the window is maximized. On the other hand, when there isn't enough space to display everything in the window, it places the main body text below the  section. In other words, it keeps moving elements around to fit the window.

Could someone please tell me how I'd achieve the look I'm going for? I've tried playing around with a few CSS attributes I read about through Google, but I'm pretty sure I don't know what I'm doing, and could really use some guidance.

Thank you!

Comment: Those tags, by themselves, do not affect the placement of the elements. You need to style them using CSS. Try reading a tutorial on CSS positioning/layout.

Comment: I know - sorry, I should have mentioned this. I have the basics of HTML5 and CSS down pat, but positioning is something I'm having trouble wrapping my head around.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an HTML5 question as much as it is a basic understanding of HTML and CSS. If you're going to jump in to web dev you're going to need to understand basic CSS like floating etc. I would recommend some tutorials on YouTube or NetTuts. Just play around with a few divs, move them around the page, manipulate them with CSS and it will start to come together. Then making a three column layout with fixed header and footer will seem like a piece of cake.

[Floating Divs w/ CSS](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=SVVZa01TrwE)

Answer (score 0):

I find CSS to be super hard. It is quite difficult to make a page that looks good and works on lots of different platforms and browsers. You may find it easiest to use a css framework, such as [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

Drop that into your website, and use it to make your layout. Use the dev tools for your browser ([Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for firefox) to examine the styles that are being applied to the various elements. Modify the styles to suit your needs.

HTML5 doesn't really give you a page layout for free. The elements you mention (`header`, `section`,etc) are used to create semantic pages, rather than to specify how they should be displayed.

Comment: I'm just curious, what is your go to programming language?

Comment: @Charlie Right now, I mainly do C#, python, Objective C and javascript. And SQL, if that counts.

Comment: Ah ok. I just saw your comment that CSS was hard and it made me wonder what you're used to. I started with CSS and HTML, and Objective C is a pain to me (I am learning slowly...). Just struck me as interesting.

Comment: I work mainly with HTML and Javascript, using Node.JS on the server-side of web applications (it's basically Javascript), and I work a lot with CSS. I still find it a pain, which is why I also use Bootstrap like Oliver does (at least I assume he does).

Answer (score 0):

Can't help much without your code. But I am sure it is because of `float` issue. add this CSS property to your footer `clear: both`

Hope it might help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're trying to make yourself a little hack, or if you're looking for a complete library that will do all this for you, but if you're looking for the latter, I recommend [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), which is a cross-platform solution for implementing many HTML5 features, and even resorts to fallbacks for non-modern browsers. The only drawback is the requirement of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) in order to initialize the components that are responsive*. However, this is optional if you are not looking to implement [these features](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html). The responsive design, amazingly, does not require javascript since it is pure CSS. Hope this helps!

*Edit: meant "interactive" there, not "responsive."

Comment: I'm going to check into this first, definitely. From the sounds of it, CSS is more of a chore than a useful tool, so perhaps a framework like this will be exactly what I need. Thank you!